# Gliders in a trailer

Tags: home-experiment, aerodynamics, thought-experiment

Everybody has heard I the old thought expirement of the birds in the trailer where the man hits the trailer the birds take flight and the trailer gets lighter. This has been disproven by the mythbusters, but what if  instead of birds there would be gliders, and they would take of when the trailer was banged. would the trailer get lighter then or would it stay the same.

PS: this is factoring out a lot of variables like turbulence and who is controlling the gliders and size of the trailer and flight time. All that matters is the trailer weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the trailer would not get lighter. The gliders are supported by the air, and the air is supported by the trailer.